# jQuery - Compare two numbers and add background property to greatest

Tags: jquery, css

I have several tables and the last row of each table contains following data :

```
<tr>
    <td>59/128 (46%)</td>
    <td>vs</td>
    <td>45/90 (54%)</td>
</tr>
```

I want to highlight greatest percentage number with yellow colour on background.

The question here is how to ignore first couple of numbers as numbers are appearing dynamically so I can't be sure how many numbers are before percentage number I need to select and compare.

I appreciate your time.

Comment: go step by step. Internet has all the answers. Find a way to loop all `td`s of last row. Find a way to get a largest value. Find a way to style an html element. It's all easy if you break it down!

Answer (score 0):

The below code is not exactly but should be enough to get you started. I have extracted the values from the last tr of the table, you can take care from there. Code is properly documented let me know if any issues. Hope this helps:)

```
<script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        //Just some array to have the values available. You don't necessarily have to do this. This will just make the values available even after the loop ends.
        var arr = new Array(3);
        var i= 0;
            //Add your table id here.
            $('#yourtableid tr:last').each(function() {
            $(this).find('td').each (function() {   
              //Iterating over each td in tr and then assigning value to each of the array element    
              arr[i] = $(this).html();
              i++;
            });  
        });
            //Values as retrieved from the td
            for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
                console.log("Values in td: " +arr[i]);
            }
        }); 
        </script>
```